# How to logout from Django with custom user model and custom logout view?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I made an app and extended `AbstractUser` to add some fields to my `User` model. After that, everything works as expected (login, create user, reset password...) but when I try to logout using the default
`django.contrib.auth.LogoutView` or `include('django.contrib.auth.urls')`
it will simply ignore the logout. When I go back to the restricted page I can enter and see the content and my user is actually logged in!

I created a custom logout view like this

```py
def custom_logout(request):
    print('Loggin out {}'.format(request.user))
    auth.logout(request)
    print(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/restrictedpage')
```

on the restrictedpage I have a print statement to show the user

```
print("User logged: {}".format(request.user))
```

When I click logout this is what shows up in the console:

```sh
"GET /restrictedpage  HTTP/1.1" 200 19820
User logged: ceterre
 ----- This is where i click logout ------
Loggin out AnonymousUser
AnonymousUser
"GET /accounts/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0  ----- this redirects me to /restrictedpage
User logged: ceterre
"GET /restrictedpage HTTP/1.1" 200 19820
```

this literally translate to:

```sh
 - I know ceterre is logged
 - logging out ceterre
 - user logged: AnonymousUser
 - redirect to restricted page (where I should have no access since im supposedly logged out)
 - user logged: ceterre (without any login or anything...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Login and logout is part of Django (and AbstractUser too) so you don't need extend this parts of code. One thing you must do is add in settings.py file this two line of code:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'template_name'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'template_name'
```

Comment: Actually i have them as
```LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/restrictedpage'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/login'``` this does not solve my problem because the problem is while logging out...

Comment: In book Django for Beginners Learn web development with Django 2.0 from William S. Vincent author describe how to extend user model using AbstractUser.  And he don't do code change in login or logout view. He use them directly in template. <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>  How method you use to extend user model? AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser? Maybe you have mistake in your code.

Comment: i used AbstractUser, because i was adding 2 additional fields to the model. i think i will setup the project again to try.... maybe my project got corrupted in some way.

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def custom_logout(request):
    print('Loggin out {}'.format(request.user))
    logout(request)
    print(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/restrictedpage')
```

This worked for me and should work for you also.

Answer (score 1):

## Django 3+: Using a custom class-based view

#### Template view

To avoid conflicts with `django.contrib.auth` and its defaults, create a new view with a unique name. Use the built-in function `django.contrib.auth.logout` to actually sign out the user.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView


class SignedOutView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "registration/signed_out.html"

    def get(self, request: HttpRequest):
        logout(request)
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

#### Template

Add a new `signed_out.html` template under the `registration` folder.

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<section id="page" class="">
  <p>You are signed out!</p>

  <p>Click <a href="{% url 'login' %}">here</a> to sign in again.</p>
</section>

{% endblock content %}
```

#### URLs

Update your URL paths.

```py
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .views import SignedOutView


urlpatterns = [
    path("accounts/", include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("signed-out/", SignedOutView.as_view(), name="sign-out"),
]
```

#### Use the new sign-out view

```py
<a href="{% url 'sign-out'%}">Sign out</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for Django 3+.

Replace `django.contrib.admin` with `my_admin` module.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        ...
        'my_admin.apps.AdminConfig',
        # 'django.contrib.admin',
        ...
]
```

AdminConfig (my_admin/apps.py):

```
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig as ContribAdminConfig

class AdminConfig(ContribAdminConfig):
    default_site = 'my_admin.admin_site.AdminSite'
```

AdminSite (my_admin/admin_site.py):

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite as ContribAdminSite
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

class AdminSite(ContribAdminSite):
    @never_cache
    def logout(self, request, extra_context=None):
        """
        Define your custom logout functionality here.
        Checkout the super logout method to get a baseline implementation.
        
        Log out the user for the given HttpRequest.
        This should *not* assume the user is already logged in.
        """

        # Your logout code here.

        return super().logout(request, extra_context)
```